# Align 3 pictures in line to rest of the page

Tags: html, css, image, alignment

I am trying to put three pictures next to each other in one line, each with a header and descrpiction undernearth it, I want the one on the right and left to align with the rest of the page, that has a **padding of 4%**, like the headers and parargaphs above, and the middle one just yeah in the middle.

But whenever I set the padding to the 4%, the right one will float underneath the first two..

```css
.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.half-width{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.third-width{
 width: 33.3333%;
 float: left;
}

img{
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
}

h1, h3{
    margin: 2% 4%;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h2, p, img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 2% 0%;
}

#right, #left{
    padding: 0 4%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>text text text 
  </h3>

  <div class="full-width">
  
  <div class="third-width" id="left">
   <img src="img/gary.jpg" alt="Gary">
   <h2>Gary</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="third-width" id="middle">
   <img src="img/howard.jpg" alt="Howard">
   <h2>Howard</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="third-width" id="right">
   <img src="img/mark.jpg" alt="Mark">
   <h2>Mark</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  </div>
 </main>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the box-sizing seems to fix your problem.

```
#right, #left{
    padding: 0 4%;
    display: block;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

See snippet

```css
.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.half-width{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.third-width{
 width: 33.3333%;
 float: left;
}

img{
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
}

h1, h3{
    margin: 2% 4%;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h2, p, img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 2% 0%;
}

#right, #left{
    padding: 0 4%;
    display: block;
 box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<h3>text text text 
  </h3>

  <div class="full-width">
  
  <div class="third-width" id="left">
   <img src="img/gary.jpg" alt="Gary">
   <h2>Gary</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="third-width" id="middle">
   <img src="img/howard.jpg" alt="Howard">
   <h2>Howard</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="third-width" id="right">
   <img src="img/mark.jpg" alt="Mark">
   <h2>Mark</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

What is happening here is the padding is getting added to the width, so the total size is wider than the page.

`4%` + `33.3%` + `4%` + `33.3%` + `4%` + `33.3%` + `4%` = Over 100%.

Reduce your 33.3% to 28%, and it will work - as below.

```css
.full-width{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.half-width{
 width: 50%;
 float: left;
}
.third-width{
 width: 28%;
 float: left;
}

img{
    height: 30%;
    width: auto;
}

h1, h3{
    margin: 2% 4%;
}

p{
    text-align: justify;
}

h2{
    text-align: center;
}

h2, p, img{
    margin: auto;
    display: block;
    padding: 2% 0%;
}

#right, #left{
    padding: 0 4%;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<h3>text text text 
  </h3>

  <div class="full-width">
  
  <div class="third-width" id="left">
   <img src="img/gary.jpg" alt="Gary">
   <h2>Gary</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="third-width" id="middle">
   <img src="img/howard.jpg" alt="Howard">
   <h2>Howard</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  <div class="third-width" id="right">
   <img src="img/mark.jpg" alt="Mark">
   <h2>Mark</h2>
   <p>text text</p>
  </div>

  </div>
 </main>
</html>
```